# text escapes the flex container on zoom

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hi i am trying to create a user card type div that has some images on the left and username on right. i could get the layout done but when zooming the text is overflown and escapes the `flex` container. here is my code. [And this is the ouptut(Try zooming in by ctrl +)](https://jsfiddle.net/anekix001/7dr8z1hp/7/)

```html
<div style="
       border: 1px solid #775CD0; 
       display:flex;
       width:20%;
       border-radius:4px;
       ">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300
    " height="30" width="30" style="  
          align-self:start;
          margin-left:10px;
          padding-top:2px;
          padding-bottom:2px;
          ">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random
    " class="image2" height="18px" width="18px" style="
          align-self:start;
          margin-top:18px;
          margin-left:-15px;
          ">
  <span class="account-name" style="
          margin-top:6px;
          padding-left:22px;
          ">
       GonFreecks
       </span>
</div>
```

Comment: It also overflows with a longer name: https://jsfiddle.net/yh1dwnga/ - this is because you've set a fixed width for the container and no handling of `overflow`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol ah i get it. but what property i use so that is fits nicely inside the container without resorting to `overflow:hidden`

Comment: Since it's a single word in this case, you'd want something like `overflow-wrap: break-word`

Comment: You can use word-break: break-all; for text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rermove the width and use display:inline-flex;

```html
<div style="
   border: 1px solid #775CD0; 
   display:inline-flex;
   
   border-radius:4px;
   ">
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300
" height="30" width="30" 
      style="  
      align-self:start;
      margin-left:10px;
      padding-top:2px;
      padding-bottom:2px;
      "
      >
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random
" class="image2" height="18px" width="18px" 
      style="
      align-self:start;
      margin-top:18px;
      margin-left:-15px;
      ">
   <span class="account-name"
      style="
      margin-top:6px;
      padding-left:22px;
      ">
   GonFreecks
   </span>
</div>
```